# How could I remove a strange header within an AJAX uploaded image with Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, upload

I want to upload an image from JS/jQuery client to a Django server.
For some reasons, I can't achieve to do this with a model. So I tried it the old way...

**Problem:** when I upload the file, the produced file contains a part of the HTTP request(?!).

**Here is my Js code:**

```
data = new FormData($('#upform-' + target.getAttribute('data-store'))[0]);
contentType = false
[...]
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
    contentType: contentType,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: "POST",
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    url: "api/" + url,
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Token ' + application.api.token);
        if( target ) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=' + target.files[0].name);
            request.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
        }
        console.log("Données envoyées : ", data);
    }
})
...
```

**Here is my Python view:**

```
    myfile = request.FILES['file']
    outputFile = open(myfile.name, 'wb+')
    rawContent = ContentFile(myfile.read())
    for chunk in rawContent.chunks():
        outputFile.write(chunk)
    outputFile.close()
```

Here is the strange header at the beginning of my "new" file when I open it with Notepad:

```
-----------------------------76672927332420
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="planning.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà
```

The end of the file also contains a "------------------------".

Thanks for your help, it drives me crazy!
Thank

Comment: Why such extra things you are doing, I could achieve this without using header and etc. I also had to use manual file upload instead of django one, because of the API work. APIs can't use the django's file upload. To overcome I've used that, if you want I can share my code with you.

Comment: That extra things came one by one trying to solve the differents error code on my backend. For example, without the header specification I get an error from Django telling me that I should specify the right header.
Indeed, I'm really curious of the code you wrote. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of you suggested, it was probably because of a malformed HTTP request. By the way, I didn't find how to solve it. So I adjusted a solution proposed on this question to manually remove the header:

```
if request.FILES['file']:
    myfile = request.FILES['file']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()

    # building a temporary file was the solution:
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
        lines = myfile.readlines()
        tmp.writelines(lines[4:-2])
        tmp.seek(0)
        fs.save(myfile.name, tmp)
```

It now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this:

```
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename=' + target.files[0].name);
```

This is making the server treat the entire `FormData` as the file being upload, rather than just the `file` element.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. When I don't specify this header, I have the following error:
**Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter.**
Should I use another content-disposition "type"?

Comment: That header is in the `FormData` itself.

Comment: When I drop the header definition, Django tells me that I should specify it and refuses to access the data. I continue to search